# How to get facet value for all fields using Java API

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I'm new to `Elasticsearch` and tried to query some sample documents. I issued the following query using the `Java API`. This query fetched me the correct result. It returned the names of all categories. Now I want the count of all names of a category. Could you explain me how to do that? I'm sorry for my bad English.

```
SearchResponse sr = client.prepareSearch()
         .addField("Category")
         .setQuery(QueryBuilders.matchAllQuery())
         .addFacet(FacetBuilders.termsFacet("f")
         .field("Category"))
         .execute()
         .actionGet();
```

Comment: facets are deprecated in elasticsearch 1.0  version>you better swithch to Aggregation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at [the Count API](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/count.html) to count your results if you not want to get the result set (matched documents) but only the count.

If you want to get the result set, you get the result size in the response for every filter or query request too.

Comment: Sorry I didn't explained question properly. See I have a "category" field. Now I want all values for this field with count of each value. For example 
{
"Category":"Mobile"
}
{
"Category":"Computer"
}
I want mobile and computer with count of them.

Comment: Ok, you need a Facet: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-facets.html. Use a filter facet if you can. Filters are cached by elasticsearch, so the response comes under 10ms.

Comment: Thanks. but I know this. and I want to implement it using java-api.

Comment: @bunny please provide the code of script facet. My requirement is same as yours.